# Gnuplot: How to plot bash array without dumping it to a file

Tags: arrays, bash, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a bash array using gnuplot without dumping the array to a temporary file.

Let's say:

```sh
myarray=$(seq 1 5)
```

I tried the following:

```sh
myarray=$(seq 1 5)
gnuplot -p  <<< "plot $myarray"
```

I got the following error:

```
         line 0: warning: Cannot find or open file "1"
         line 0: No data in plot


gnuplot> 2
         ^
         line 0: invalid command


gnuplot> 3
         ^
         line 0: invalid command


gnuplot> 4
         ^
         line 0: invalid command


gnuplot> 5''
         ^
         line 0: invalid command
```

Why it doesn't interpret the array as a data block?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> bash array
>
> myarray=$(seq 1 5)

The `myarray` is **not** a bash array, it is a normal variable.

The easiest is to put the data to stdin and plot `<cat`.

```
seq 5 | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "<cat" w l'
```

Or with your variable and with using a here-string:

```
<<<"$myarray" gnuplot -p -e 'plot "<cat" w l'
```

Or with your variable with redirection with `echo` or `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n" "$myarray" | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "<cat" w l'
```

And if you want to plot an actual array, just print it on separate lines and then pipe to gnuplot

```
array=($(seq 5))
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "<cat" w l'
```

Comment: or `echo $myarray | tr " " "\n" | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "<cat" w l'`

Comment: Avoid useless use of `cat`!  Use *`STDIN`* instead, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60026699/1848245)

Answer (score 1):

## Plot *STDIN*

```
gnuplot -p -e 'plot "/dev/stdin"'
```

Sample:

```
( seq 5 10; seq 7 12 ) | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "/dev/stdin"'
```

or

```
gnuplot -p -e 'plot "/dev/stdin" with steps'  < <( seq 5 10; seq 7 12 )
```

#### More tunned plot

```
gnuplot -p -e "set terminal wxt 0 enhanced;set grid;
    set label \"Test demo with random values\" at 0.5,0 center;
    set yrange [ \"-1\" : \"80\" ] ; set timefmt \"%s\";
    plot \"/dev/stdin\" using 1:2 title \"RND%30+40\" with impulse;"  < <(

          paste <(
                seq 2300 2400
          ) <(
                for ((i=101;i--;)){ echo $[RANDOM%30+40];}
          )
)
```

Please note that this is still *one line*, you could *Copy'n paste* into any terminal console.